# TextArea not drawing complete text on libgdx

Tags: libgdx, textarea

I'm using a TextArea in a stage in libgdx. On linux works great, but on Windows (7)  when I write (or copy and paste) a long text to the TextArea, there is a region that do not display the text.  The text is there, but in that specific region doesn't display it. I'm using a modification of the default skin (I changed to Linear, Linear instead on Nearest, Nearest), and I'm using freefonttype (linear, linear too).  There is a picture on how it looks on linux, and how it looks on windows.

```
    textEntry = new TextArea("enter text here.", AssetLoader.skin);
    textEntry.setBounds(AssetLoader.LINE_START, 80, 540, 600);
    stage.addActor(textEntry);
```

The following pictures show how it looks on linux and windows. The text is exactly the same.

[image: same text using linux and windows where it isn't shown correctly]

Any suggestions??

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some testing in other (real) machines, I found out that it is a virtual-box issue (I was trying it on virtualized windows machines).

More info: https://www.virtualbox.org/ticket/11889